# First order logic translation error?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

For the sentence, "nothing is larger than everything".

I translated it into (∀x (x) --> (~∀y (y) --> Larger(x,y)))

But I'm told that this is incorrect it should actually ∀x ~(x is larger than everything)?

I am seriously confused and don't understand how this can be. Can anybody elucidate on this please.

Comment: What do you mean by starting your attempt with "for all x" and then continuing with $(x) \to [something]$? What does it mean for the variable $x$ to imply something? It seems you're mixing up quantifiers with variables in some way.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the (x)--> part and the (y)--> part your translation is OK, and only diffrs by the fact that you go the extra step of spelling out "not(x is larger than everything)."

Usually one *either* writes $\forall x F(x)$ to mean for all x F(x) is true, *or* writes it $(x)F(x).$ That is these are the two common ways to quantify a statement $F(x)$ to signify it is true for all $x.$

The sentence "not(x is larger than everything) would be spelled out by saying "not(for all y Larger(x,y))" as you did, as long as you include the obvious definition that "Larger(x,y)" stands for the relation x is larger than y. In short, apart from the notation issue your translation is the same as your quoted answer, and in my opinion is more "complete" in spelling it out.

Comment: Your answer is just fine @coffeemath. Besides, it helps if the asker can get multiple perspectives.

Comment: Thanks, @GauravChandan --- I'll leave it up, as you say questioner may get another idea...

Answer (score 1):

The statement ~($x$ is larger than everything) *can* be translated as ~$[(\forall y)(larger(x,y))]$, which you *have* almost done correctly (note that the tilde (~) should be outside the whole statement (and not inside it next to the $\forall$) because it's a negation of the statement as a whole and even if not $\forall y$ is not really something that can be true or false.

There's also no need for conditionals because the statements $\forall y$ and $\forall x$ are not really conditions, they have no truth table(is another way of looking at it). Finally, $(x)$ and $(y)$ don't make much sense and should be omitted.

So you are *almost* right, but the translation should have been, $(\forall x)$~$[(\forall y)(larger(x,y))]$

You can even simplify the negation to make it, $(\forall x)[(\exists y)(larger(y,x))]$, but that's just up to you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Gaurav-- After typing my answer I read yours which is just as good maybe better to explain things. So I'll upvote. [If you think I should delete mine, I would.]

Answer (score 0):

I would simply write $\neg\bigl(\exists x\ \forall y\ (x > y)\bigr)$ or, equivalently, $\forall x\ \exists y\ \neg (x > y)$.